# I think this should raise an error, but it doesn't

Tags: python, error-handling

Below is a simple function to remove duplicates in a list while preserving order. I've tried it and it actually works, so the problem here is my understanding. It seems to me that the second time you run `uniq.remove(item)` for a given item, it will return an error (`KeyError` or `ValueError` I think?) because that item has already been removed from the unique set. Is this not the case?

```
def unique(seq):
    uniq = set(seq)  
    return [item for item in seq if item in uniq and not uniq.remove(item)]
```

Comment: @katrielalex -- I don't.  Using a condition for the side-effect of removing and item from a collection leads to confusing, hard to read code. (IMHO)

Comment: Plus you are creating an entire new `set` and popping every item from it just to act as a filter on a list.  I can't imagine this is faster, and it definitely isn't clearer, than a single pass (for creating a new de-duped list) or double pass (for in-place de-duping of the list) `for` loop.

Comment: For anyone interested, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-python-whilst-preserving-order contains various options for doing this same operation in different ways.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a check `if item in uniq` which gets executed before the item is removed.  The `and` operator is nice in that it "short circuits".  This means that if the condition on the left evaluates to `False`-like, then the condition on the right doesn't get evaluated -- We already know the expression can't be `True`-like.

Comment: Thanks very much for this. What value does uniq.remove(item) return? I'm guessing the whole "and not uniq.remove(item)" is a way to run methods in a list comprehension rather than changing the whole thing to a for loop, but I'm not sure why, for example, we use "and not" in this case instead of just "and." Presumably b/c unique.remove(item) returns None or False?

Comment: `uniq.remove(item)` returns `None`.  `not None` returns `True`.

Answer (score 4):

`set.remove` is an in-place operation. This means that it does not return anything (well, it returns `None`); and `bool(None)` is `False`.

So your list comprehension is effectively this:

```
answer = []
for item in seq:
    if item in uniq and not uniq.remove(item):
        answer.append(item)
```

and since python does short circuiting of conditionals (as others have pointed out), this is effectively:

```
answer = []
for item in seq:
    if item in uniq:
        if not uniq.remove(item):
            answer.append(item)
```

Of course, since `unique.remove(item)` returns `None` (the `bool` of which is `False`), either both conditions are evaluated or neither.

The reason that the second condition exists is to remove `item` from `uniq`. This way, if/when you encounter `item` again (as a duplicate in `seq`), it will not be found in `uniq` because it was deleted from `uniq` the last time it was found there.

Now, keep in mind, that this is fairly dangerous as conditions that modify variables are considered bad style (imagine debugging such a conditional when you aren't fully familiar with what it does). Conditionals should really not modify the variables they check. As such, they should only read the variables, not write to them as well.

Hope this helps

Comment: "The main reason for the second condition ..." -> "the **only** reason for the second condition ..."  :D.  It might be worth pointing out that some consider it a little rude to use conditions for side-effects like this.

Answer (score 1):

mgilson and others has answered this question nicely, as usual. I thought I might point out what is probably the canonical way of doing this in python, namely using the `unique_everseen` recipe from the [recipe section](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) of the `itertools` docs, quoted below:

```
from itertools import ifilterfalse

def unique_everseen(iterable, key=None):
    "List unique elements, preserving order. Remember all elements ever seen."
    # unique_everseen('AAAABBBCCDAABBB') --> A B C D
    # unique_everseen('ABBCcAD', str.lower) --> A B C D
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    if key is None:
        for element in ifilterfalse(seen.__contains__, iterable):
            seen_add(element)
            yield element
    else:
        for element in iterable:
            k = key(element)
            if k not in seen:
                seen_add(k)
                yield element
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def unique_with_order(seq):
    final = []
    for item in seq:
        if item not in final:
            final.append(item)
    return final


print unique_with_order([1,2,3,3,4,3,6])
```

Break it down, make it simple :) Not everything has to be a list comprehension these days.

Comment: Of course, not everything! Because we have dict comprehensions and generator comprehensions :)

Comment: I have no problem with this as a way to make a list unique -- However I don't think that it help OP with the conceptual understanding about why the expression actually works.

Comment: I do have a problem with this way of doing it.  It's O(n²).

Comment: @SvenMarnach -- Great point.  I just glanced at the code and assumed that `final` was a `set` and he was appending to a different list.  I suppose I should have looked at it more closely.

Comment: @SvenMarnach -- I wonder if there's a better way to do this *if* order matters **and** the objects are unhashable.  It seems like this might be the best you can do in that case ... (I googled quickly and didn't turn up anything to the contrary, although that doesn't mean a better solution doesn't exist)

Comment: @mgilson If you can construct a hashable key from the objects you could use the `unique_everseen` recipe from my answer with a key function.

Comment: @lazyr -- Yeah, but objects which are unhashable are usually unhashable for a reason :).  Creating a hash for them on the go seems a little sketchy.

Comment: @mgilson Isn't the reason usually that they're mutable? If that's the reason then I don't think there's normally a problem preventing changes temporarily during the uniqueifying operation (i.e. don't call any external functions while uniquefying, if single-threaded), and if so then you may just use a key that "freezes" the mutable.

Comment: @lazyr -- fair point.  I was thinking that we were comparing lists from different places, but we're not.  You might be right.  That might be one (sneaky) way to go about doing it.

Answer (score 0):

@mgilson's answer is the right one, but here, for your information, is a possible lazy ([generator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained)) version of the same function. This means it'll work for iterables that don't fit in memory - including infinite iterators - as long as the set of its elements will.

```
def unique(iterable):
    uniq = set()
    for item in iterable:
        if item not in uniq:
            uniq.add(item)
            yield item
```

Answer (score -1):

The first time you run this function, you will get `[1,2,3,4]` from your list comprehension and the set `uniq` will be emptied. The second time you run this function, you will get `[]` because your set `uniq` will be empty. The reason you don't get any errors on the second run is that Python's `and` short circuits - it sees the first clause (`item in uniq`) is false and doesn't bother to run the second clause.

Comment: I'm sorry for the downvote, but this just isn't clear.  What do you mean the second time you run the function you'll get `[]`?  Why would the set `uniq` be empty?

Comment: `uniq` is empty because `uniq.remove(item)` empties it. The list comprehension doesn't short circuit the first time through. I'll edit my answer to spell it out.

Comment: `uniq` gets rebuilt every time the function is called by the line `uniq = set(seq)`

Comment: Oh, you are correct. And that's the answer to his question. He wanted to know why he wasn't getting a `KeyError`; it's because `uniq` is method-local and gets reset each time the method is called.

Comment: Daniel, thanks for this. My question wasn't phrased optimally, as I meant when you loop through a particular iterable/list, what happens when you hit the duplicate and the item has already been removed from uniq. That said, I could see why it sounds like I meant what happens when you call the method the second time around. Thanks for your input.